# Import error for python lxml module

Tags: python, anaconda, lxml, python-3.5, conda

I am using conda virtual environment and I have intsalled the lxml module using `conda install lxml`. The package was successfully installed but when I open python in my terminal and do `import lxml`, I get the following error:

```
`>>> import lxml
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lxml'
`
```

I don't understand what is the issue here.

My installed packages are as follows:

```
`# packages in environment at /users/deepayan/miniconda3/envs/pytorch:
#
hdf5                      1.8.17                        1  
jbig                      2.1                           0  
jpeg                      8d                            2  
libiconv                  1.14                          0    anaconda
libpng                    1.6.27                        0  
libtiff                   4.0.6                         2  
libxml2                   2.9.4                         0    anaconda
libxslt                   1.1.29                        0    anaconda
lxml                      3.8.0                    py36_0  
mkl                       2017.0.1                      0  
numpy                     1.12.1                   py36_0  
opencv                    3.1.0               np112py36_1  
openssl                   1.0.2l                        0  
pip                       9.0.1                    py36_1  
python                    3.6.1                         2  
readline                  6.2                           2  
setuptools                27.2.0                   py36_0  
sqlite                    3.13.0                        0  
tk                        8.5.18                        0  
wheel                     0.29.0                   py36_0  
xz                        5.2.2                         1  
zlib                      1.2.8                         3  
`
```

All other packages can be imported error free, the problem is only with lxml. If anyone can suggest a way out, I'd be very grateful. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you're inside the correct virtual environment?

Comment: yes @athul.sure I am pretty sure I am inside the correct environment.

Comment: create new virtualenv then install all package again.

Comment: then activate this virtualenv and use python shell

Comment: okay, @ammy will try this, but do you have any idea as to why it is happening?

Comment: seems the issue is fixed, the lxml package was for python 3.6 version, so I just had to upgrade my python from 3.5 to 3.6. weird though ryt??

Comment: the install path is not find for import lxml.